# Performance issue with JDBC and Oracle Db

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query that has different execution times via Sql developer (around 0.5 s) and via Oracle JDBC driver.

So query is:

```
select combina0_.eid as col_0_0_, combina0_.bid as col_1_0_, 
  combina0_.pid as col_2_0_, combina0_.status as col_3_0_, 
  combina0_.mid as col_4_0_, combina0_.core_approval_status as col_5_0_,
   combina0_.approval_status as col_6_0_, combina0_.tid as col_7_0_, 
  combina0_.artificial_id as col_8_0_ 
from
 mydb._combination_item combina0_ where (combina0_.artificial_id 
  in ('id1', 'id2', ...1000 string ids..., 'id1000') and 
  (combina0_.status not in  ('INACTIVE') or combina0_.status is null)
```

If I execute it via Sql Developer trace shows this

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        3      0.01       0.02          0       1258          0        1000
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        5      0.01       0.02          0       1258          0        1000

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 51  (TEST_DB_USER_RW)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
      1000       1000       1000  TABLE ACCESS FULL COMBINATION_ITEM (cr=1258 pr=0 pw=0 time=3316 us cost=407 size=20600 card=200)


Rows     Execution Plan
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  SELECT STATEMENT   MODE: ALL_ROWS
   1000   TABLE ACCESS   MODE: ANALYZED (FULL) OF 'COMBINATION_ITEM' 
              (TABLE)

********************************************************************************
```

while if I execute it using either via Hibernate or via direct JDBC query, trace shows this

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch        2     23.75      24.80          0       1256          0        1000
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        4     23.75      24.80          0       1256          0        1000

Misses in library cache during parse: 0
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 51  (TEST_DB_USER_RW)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
      1000       1000       1000  TABLE ACCESS FULL COMBINATION_ITEM (cr=1256 pr=0 pw=0 time=2294738 us cost=342 size=103000 card=1000)


Rows     Execution Plan
-------  ---------------------------------------------------
      0  SELECT STATEMENT   MODE: ALL_ROWS
   1000   TABLE ACCESS   MODE: ANALYZED (FULL) OF 'COMBINATION_ITEM' 
              (TABLE)




********************************************************************************
```

Can you please suggest me the steps that I can take to speed up JDBC execution. 
Currently fetch size is set to 1000 and changing it doesn't affect JDBC query performance too much.

Comment: SQL Developer ALSO uses the Oracle jdbc driver. When you execute a query, it only does a single fetch, and the default fetch size is 50. We've found setting it higher to 1000 for example is usually detrimental to performance. So, run your query as a script (F5) in SQL Developer, that will fetch the entire result set, and will be a better test.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith well, actually it was the test, running on 200 (this is my default in sql developer gives even lesser times around 0.15)

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: all of your time is around the fetch, so the answer is there somewhere. Maybe @krisrice will have a better answer/insight

Comment: Need to see the java code to see what's going on to be sure. Just guessing either 2 different envs or 2 different sqls are being run. these are different in each which if identical should be the same... cost, size, card